# Magento 2.4.4 sample data installation error

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento2.4

I have downloaded Magento version 2.4.4 with sample data from https://magento.com/tech-resources/download I was trying to install it on the Wamp server. But when I run the installation I get the error

```
Unable to apply data patch Magento\GroupedProductSampleData\Setup\Patch\Data\InstallGroupedProductSampleData for module Magento_GroupedProductSampleData. Original exce
  ption message: Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly.
```

I tried with versions 2.4.3 and 2.4.3-p2 all are showing the same error. But I was able to install the 2.4.3 version without sample data. I searched and found it is related to some error in the csv file. But none of the answers provided a  solution. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Akhilesh in our case use magento 2.4.4 and this error was by a third module and when disable this, all magento run fine.

Your can edit vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php file, search rollback() method and in the "else" section add this line:

```
echo (new \Exception())->getTraceAsString();
```

This can help you to look where is the error, if is from a module or another.

Regards